# If-Else in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write a procedure to perform withdraw operation that only permits a withdrawal, if there is sufficient funds in the account then update the Account table and print  the message, 'Transaction successful.' else print, 'Insufficient Amount.' . The procedure should take Account_id and withdrawal amount as input.

```
Account:
ACCNO   NUMBER  PK
CUSTOMER_NAME   VARCHAR2(30)     
BALANCE NUMBER(15,2)     

12345   Williams    23455.6
23456   Robert  43221
34521   John    23449
```

Functional Requirement:

```
procedure withdraw(ano number , amt number)
```

Sample input:

```
withdraw(12345, 2000);
```

Sample output:

```
Transaction successful.
```

I tried to write this code which is as follows-

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace procedure withdraw(ano number, amt number) is withdraw_operation account%rowtype;
begin
select * into withdraw_operation from account 
if (amt > balance)
then dbms_output.put_line('Transaction successful');
else dbms_output.put_line('Insufficient Amount');
end if;
end;
```

But this is not showing any output nor error, please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is not showing any output **nor error**

This is hard to believe because what you posted isn't correct.

---

Anyway: from what you posted, should be something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM account;

     ACCNO CUSTOMER    BALANCE
---------- -------- ----------
     12345 Williams    23455,6
     23456 Robert        43221
     34521 John          23449
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE withdraw (ano NUMBER, amt NUMBER)
  2  IS
  3     withdraw_operation  account%ROWTYPE;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT *
  6       INTO withdraw_operation
  7       FROM account
  8      WHERE accno = ano;
  9
 10     IF amt > withdraw_operation.balance
 11     THEN
 12        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Transaction successful');
 13     ELSE
 14        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Insufficient Amount');
 15     END IF;
 16  END;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXEC withdraw(12345, 2000);
Insufficient Amount

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, the compiler I use is not showing any errors too! Even this code, which you have given is not giving any output or error. I'm feeling helpless. Can you please try again and check for error if any?

Comment: No problem. I tried it and edited my answer which shows that procedure got created and was successfully executed.

Comment: Yes, this worked just fine, but the only changes that had to be made was - `IF amt < withdraw_operation.balance
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Transaction successful');
      ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Insufficient Amount');
     END IF;` Thank you so much for the help! :)